# Keeping colors when repainting canvas.?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, colors, repaint

Here's my code:

```
public void Repaint() {
        canvas1.Children.Clear();
        ObservableCollection<ClassBox> classes = viewModel.Classes;
        foreach (ClassBox j in classes) {
            // connect our ui element to the mouse handler if not done already
            if (!j.MouseActive) {
                j.Box.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += Handle_MouseUp;
                j.Box.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += Handle_MouseDown;
                j.Box.PreviewMouseMove += Handle_MouseMove;
                j.MouseActive = true;
                // Heres should the code be written (something like :)
                // j.Box.SetColor(Change_Color(value));
            }
            canvas1.Children.Add(j.Box);
       } }
```

So the above code presents how the boxes are being repainted when im calling the method.
Works fine but now for the next part of the code:

```
 private void Change_ColourBox(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = sender as FrameworkElement;
        ObservableCollection<ClassBox> classes = viewModel.Classes;
        foreach (ClassBox j in classes)
        {
            // connect our ui element to the mouse handler if not done already
            if (sender == BoxStandard)
            {
                j.Box.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                j.Box.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                Repaint();
            } }
```

This code tell that we should change color when the button `"Change_Color"` is pressed. 
I have implemented the buttons in XAML and I have given them names, in this case `"BoxStandard"`.

The next code snipp is where i spawn the box via an event handler.

```
 private void Spawn_Box(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) {
      viewModel.GetURController.AddAndExecute(new AddClassCommand(viewModel));
    }
```

Im gonna line it up: I give predefined colors to my elements which they start out with. When I change the colors via the click event "Change_Color" they change to the desired color. BUT when I then spawn a new element to the canvas its in the predefined color. I want to spawn it with the changed color.

Ask if you don't understand question I can explain deeper!

- The ClassBox is an object which consists of properties for the boxes. The repaint is not only for foreground/background color its also calculating the difference in positioning of the boxes

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What is ClassBox? A custom control? You do not need to tell WPF to repaint, it will do it itself when it seems the foreground/background of the UIElement have changed.

Comment: The ClassBox is an object which consists of properties for the boxes.
The repaint is not only for foreground/background color its also calculating the difference in positioning of the boxes.

Comment: What is your problem for now? Will the elements in the canvas not show the color you set?

Comment: Im gonna line it up: I give predefined colors to my elements which they start out with. When I change the colors via the click event "Change_Color" they change to the desired color. BUT when I then spawn a new element to the canvas its in the predefined color. I want it to spawn the changed color.

Comment: So post your spawn code. Sounds like you're not copying the brushes across.

Comment: Just edited so it now have the spawn code aswell